# Saving multiple plots to different pdf files within one python script

Tags: python

Here's the current code I have. It's supposed to plot multiple plots onto 2 different graphs, which it does correctly (the outputs of `plt.show()` are as they should be), but when I go to check the files generated, the same figure is saved in both `graph1.pdf` and `graph2.pdf`, and it's the one that should only be in `graph1.pdf`. I tried using `pdf.clf()` before saving the second plot and that only results in the said plot saving blank while the first still saves correctly. Any idea what I'm missing?

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint as odin
import numpy as np

pdf = plt.figure()


phi_w_0 = [1.5,0]
damp = [0.02 , 0.05 , 0.1 , 0.2]

t = np.linspace(0,200,1000)

def f(w,t):
    return [w[1] , -(B*w[1]) + np.sin(w[0])] 

for B in damp:
    result = odin(f , phi_w_0 , t)
    plt.plot(t , result[:,1] , label='$ \\beta = $ %1.2lf ' % B)

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('$ \\tau $')
plt.ylabel('$ \\phi $')
plt.show()
pdf.savefig("graph1.pdf")

plt.close()

def g(w,t): 
    return [w[1] , -(B*w[1]) + np.sin(w[0])]

for B in damp:
    result = odin(g , phi_w_0 , t)
    plt.plot(t , result[:,1] , label='$ \\beta = $ %1.2lf ' % B)

plt.legend()
plt.xlabel('$ \\tau $')
plt.ylabel('E')
plt.show()
pdf.savefig("graph2.pdf")
```

Comment: You might be missing a `pdf = plt.figure()` before the second saving.

Comment: You're reusing the same `pdf` object. Create a new one to create a new file (instead of just a copy of the same file).

Comment: So something like `pdf1` and `pdf2` for each respective file, but both with the same definition of `plt.figure()`?

Comment: One Issue I think is you need to put `plt.savefig("graph1.pdf")` before `plt.show()`.  That may explain the blank pdf.

Answer (score 0):

```
pdf.clf()
pdf = plt.figure()
```

solved it. Turns out I was on the right track with thinking I have to clear it, but I didn't realize I have to call it again afterwards. Thank you!